# SQL Query for the condition 0 AND 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in Database

[image: I have 2 tables Sales & Stock]

I want to fetch the records except (sales=0 && quantity-0) from sales table and (stock=0 && quantity=0) from stock table.

Using the select query with different conditions are not giving the required result.

I want the selected result

[image: Wanted this required result]

Comment: please don't use image. Post your sample data and query as text

Comment: `sales <> 0 OR quantity <> 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `OR` between condition of the same table as follows:

```
(s.sale <> 0 OR s.quantity <> 0) AND  (st.stock <> 0 OR st.quantity <> 0)
```

You can also use the `NOT` as follows:

```
not (s.sale = 0 and s.quantity = 0) AND not (st.stock = 0 and st.quantity = 0)
```